# Error: Exception: Error parsing asset file! Flutter App with advance_pdf_viewer

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to develop an app in flutter to display a pdf file
but I am not managing to load the file from the `assets`

This is my code:

```
class PDFPages extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PDFPagevvvState createState() => _PDFPagevvvState();
}

class _PDFPagesState extends State<PDFPagevvv> {
  PDFDocument _doc;
  bool _loading;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initPdf();
  }

  _initPdf() async {
    setState(() {
      _loading = true;
    });
    final doc = await PDFDocument.fromAsset(Assets.assetsSample);
    setState(() {
      _doc = doc;
      _loading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("test"),
      ),
      body: _loading
          ? Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            )
          : PDFViewer(
              document: _doc,
              indicatorBackground: Colors.red,
              // showIndicator: false,
              // showPicker: false,
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

In fact it's almost the same as the sample

This is the error:

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] 
Unhandled Exception: Exception: Error reading PDF! 
#0 PDFDocument.fromAsset (package:advance_pdf_viewer/src/document.dart:78:7) <asynchronous suspension> 
#1 _PDFPageState._initPdf (package:pdfview.dart:31:17) <asynchronous suspension>
```

I have tried to solve like
https://github.com/lohanidamodar/pdf_viewer/issues/50#issuecomment-852104442
but It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a conflict of File in dart:io

Edit the document.dart file (part of advance_pdf_viewer) and change...

```
import 'dart:io';
```

to

```
import 'dart:io' as io;
```

then in fromAsset, change...

```
File file;
```

to

```
io.File file;
```

and anywhere else you find **File**